# Make new Levels of categorical variable in new Variable Column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a newbee to R so got stuck here.. I have a categorical data

```
levels(df$SO)
"SO1", "SO2","SO3","SO4","SO5","SO6",SO7",SO8"
```

I want to re-categorize these levels as follows BUT SAVE THEM AS NEW COLUMN (df$newSO) IN SAME DATAFRAME.

```
levels(df$newSO)
"Unknown", "Known","Disease","Control"
```

Here `Unknown` is made of SO1 and SO2 levels, `Known` consists of SO3 and SO4. `Disease` contains SO5,SO6 and SO7. `Control` contains S8. 
I am using following

```
levels(df$SC)[levels(df$SC)%in%c("SOC1","SOC2")] <- "Unknown"
```

But it is renaming the levels in same column (df$SO). I want previous column intact while creating new column of new levels. How to do this in R?

Comment: Just do: `df$new_column<-ifelse(my_vector %in% c("SO1","SO2"),"Unknown","Known")`

Comment: Isnt that ifelse function is only if we have TWO categories like in this example "unknown" and "known". But in real my data has to recategorize into 10 categories out of 40 levels or categories. So forexample there are three new levels. "Unknown", "Known" and "Control". Then can it be done with ifelse

Comment: Use `dput(head(df,n))` to provide a sample of your actual data for better "help".

Comment: Please see my edited question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly, you can use nested `ifelse` or `case_when` and the like but with many levels, it may be better to treat it at the source.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
df$newSO <- ifelse(df$SO %in% c("SOC1", "SOC2"), "Unknown", "Known")
```

Comment: Isnt that ifelse function is only if we have TWO categories like in this example "unknown" and "known". But in real my data has to recategorize into 10 categories out of 40 levels or categories. So forexample there are three new levels. "Unknown", "Known" and "Control". Then can it be done with ifelse??

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` and `forcats` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

example <- data.frame(SO = factor(c("SO1", "SO2", "SO3", "SO4",
                                    "SO5", "SO6", "SO7", "SO8")))

result <- example %>%
  mutate(newSO = fct_collapse(SO,
                              Unknown = c("SO1", "SO2"),
                              Known = c("SO3", "SO4"),
                              Disease = c("SO5", "SO6", "SO7"),
                              Control = "SO8"))
```